# How to insert range of numbers to database in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How to insert to database range of numbers like this:

```
<form>
        <input class="form-control"></input>  <!-- insert first number -->
        <input class="form-control"></input>  <!-- insert last number -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add numbers to database</button>
    </form>
```

in example:

first input: 1
second input: 100

this form should via ng-model add the items [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...,100] to database.

I just don't know how to make some loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to recover the min and the max value and try to loop in the contoller like that with a ng-click on the button :

the html

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="myCTRL.minValue"></input>  <!-- insert first number -->
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="myCTRL.maxValue"></input>  <!-- insert last number -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myCtrl.addRangeinArray()">Add numbers to database</button></form>
```

in the javascript

```
function addRangeinArray() {
 for (number = vm.minValue;number < vm.maxValue;++number) {
  mytab.push(number);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value into the model like,

controller:

```
 $scope.range;
 $scope.insertRange = function(range){
    var rangeNumbers=[];
  for(var i=range.first;i <= range.last;i++){
     rangeNumbers.push(i);
  }
 // call to api to save rangeNumbers
 }
```

html:

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="range.first"></input>  <!-- insert first number -->
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="range.last"></input>  <!-- insert last number -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="insertRange(range)">Add numbers to database</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `es5` you can try [underscore range function](http://underscorejs.org/#range)

```
 _.range = function(start, stop, step) {
    if (arguments.length <= 1) {
      stop = start || 0;
      start = 0;
    }
    step = arguments[2] || 1;
    var len = Math.max(Math.ceil((stop - start) / step), 0);
    var idx = 0;
    var range = new Array(len);
    while(idx < len) {
      range[idx++] = start;
      start += step;
    }
    return range;
  };

_.range(1, 101);
=>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8..., 100]
```

Or if you are using `es2015` you can do like

```
Array.from(Array(100), (v, k) => k + 1);
=>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8..., 100]
```